# SQL MAX datetime - 1 day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, subquery

I want to do a comparison between two dates. The highest date (currently via MAX datetime) is working, but I can't get the day after the highest date to compare the data with.

I'm using the following to get the data of the highest available date:

```
SELECT `datetime`, `standardSubscriptionDuration`,
SUM(`activeStandardPriceSubscriptions`) AS OneMonthActiveStandard
FROM `Subscription_totals`
WHERE `standardSubscriptionDuration` = '1 Month'
AND `datetime` = (SELECT MAX(`datetime`) AS Date FROM `Subscription_totals`)";
```

I already tried:

```
(SELECT MAX(`datetime`) -1 AS Date
```

But this won't give the result. How am I able to get the data of yesterday and eventually compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want the following date arithmetics:

```
WHERE 
    `standardSubscriptionDuration` = '1 Month' 
    AND `datetime` = (
            SELECT MAX(`datetime`) - interval 1 day AS Date FROM `Subscription_totals`
    )
```